# Is there any algorithm better than trial division to factor huge numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, prime-factorization, big-numbers

Suppose , we want to find prime factors of a huge number $N$ , say $N=3^{3^{3^3}}+2$. We can assume that we can find easily $N\mod p$ for some positive integer $p$ (as it is the case in the example) , but $N$ is too big to handle numbers with approximately this site directly.

> Can we do any better than to apply the simple trial division ? The methods I am aware of all need numbers not much smaller than $N$ as the Pollard-Rho or the p-1-method.

But maybe , I missed some method that allows to find , say , $20$ digit factors with a reasonable amount of effort. Any references or ideas ?

Comment: Wiki suggests this $N$ would be amenable to the [special number field sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_number_field_sieve).

Comment: @eyeballfrog I know that this algorithm can be accelerated if the exponent is large , but does it not require that we work with numbers with magnitude comparable to $N$ ?

Comment: Ah, to clarify, you're looking for an algorithm that, if $N$ has a relatively small prime factor $q$, only uses numbers in the computation not much larger than $q$ to find it, right?

Comment: They must be small enough to be handled directly efficiently , say upto $1\ 000$ digits. In particular , an old problem of me and some other user is to find a prime factor of $$2\uparrow \uparrow 4+3\uparrow \uparrow 4$$ According to my calculations, there is no prime factor below $3\cdot 10^{11}$.

Comment: If 3 mod 4 it has an odd number of 3 mod 4 prime factors... similar for 5 mod 6